# Toshiba laptop won't even pretend to turn on

Tags: windows-7, laptop

So my laptop keeps breaking. I've tried the following, in this order. When I do it, the laptop works for about 3 hours then breaks:

- Replaced the power strip twice
- Replaced the battery (I just got the replacement today)

I don't remember the errors from when I replaced the power strip, but with the new battery, when I turn it on, it'd stay on for a while, then say that an external device had failed. I had absolutely NOTHING plugged into the laptop... No monitor cable, external mouse/keyboard, power supply (the manual told me to let it run out before using it... the battery wasn't dead yet, the computer has only been on for about 2 hours, and all but 10 mins was spent in sleep), etc...

When pressing the power on button, it doesn't even begin to turn on, no bios screen etc.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the details of your model Toshiba, as well as the specifics as to your power adapter?  It is entirely possible that you are using an adapter that is under-powered.

Comment: It's the adaptor that came in the box.

Comment: EXcellent.  Progress.  Now.  What model Toshiba is it, and are the power details off the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your battery is currently dead.

"External device" is sometimes a misnomer - and can refer to components that were added to the motherboard post initial production, as well as other devices which are external to the motherboard, but internal to the laptop itself.

Does your BIOS have a hardware test mode? Try running that after you've charged your battery.

Comment: I can't get to my BIOS, and I got a replacement battery today.

Comment: Have you recharged the battery?

Comment: Yes, but even with the cord plugged in nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the battery and plugging it in. Tells us of any errors or beeps that it makes.

Comment: No beeps, no errors, just won't turn on. Still doesn't work even with the battery removed.

Comment: Do you have a way to verify the power adapter is working?

Comment: The thing I plug into the wall? Yes, the light on it turns on when I plug it in.

Comment: It's a safe bet you need a new laptop. The hard drive or motherboard may be fried.

Comment: Alright, I'll get a new one... Do you have a guess as to what part/s may be causing it? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: So nothing happens at all when you press the power button? Or can you hear the fan start up and shutdown a second latter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9765/discussion-between-celeritas-and-chipperyman573)